# Scaling of QGraphicsProxyWidget on Qml scaleChanged

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qgraphicsview, qt-quick

I use the QCustomPlot library (QWidget-based plotting library) inside an existing application that mainly consist of a `QDeclarativeView` UI.

I have derived from `QGraphicsProxyWidget` a QmlPlot class that i expose to Qml via a plugin, and i insert the QCustomPlot Widget with setWidget() method.

This works pretty good, and I can instanciate it like so in qml.

```
Item {
    id: plotAnchor
    anchors.top: iMainCourbe.top
    anchors.bottom: iMainCourbe.bottom
    anchors.left: iMainCourbe.left
    anchors.right: iMainCourbe.right
    QmlPlot {
        id: qcpproxy
        anchors.fill: plotAnchor
        //otherstuff
        rootScale: automate.scale
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: borders
        anchors.fill: plotAnchor
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "red"
        border.width: 2
    }
}
```

This is part of a bigger component with several other sub-components.

This is part of a simulation project. We want to simulate a Digital recorder.
All dimensions (and font size, border width etc..) are well defined in the specification of said digital recorder, therefore I have decided to give the root component fixed height and width corresponding to the resolution of the digital recorder's screen.
This way we can set all the dimensions of the qml sub-components according to the spec, and the proportions are perfect.

However, I need to display the qml components to scale (1:1) in the end, and therefore using some calculations based on the display screen size (of the computer) and its dpi, I **scale** the root item  using its `scale` property,  to achieve this 1:1 ratio.

DigitalRecorder.qml

```
BaseComponent {
    id: iMain

    width: 320
    height: 240
    scale: someFunction()
}
```

This works very well for all the qml based components, but for the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` it looks very pixelated.
From what I could gather from the debugger, the QPixmap buffer size isn't scaled and neither is the viewport of the widget.
The Widget keeps drawing on the same small surface, and the result is then scaled (poorly) by Qml.

**What I have tried :**

I ignored the transformations on the `QGraphicsProxyWidget`.
Then I called `QGraphicsWidget::resize()` manually with the scaled dimensions that I computed manually, and i get a much better result, in terms of the quality of the image, since
the QPixmap buffer and the viewport of the contained widget are resized accordingly

```
QmlPlot::QmlPlot(QDeclarativeItem *parent):
    QGraphicsProxyWidget(parent),
    m_rtplot(NULL)
{
    connect(parentItem(), SIGNAL(scaleChanged()), SLOT(rescaleFromQml())); // This cannot work because parentitem() is null here and moreover scaleChanged() isn't emmited byt the children of the root item when the root item is scaled.. 
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations, true); // this ignores scaling

    m_rtplot = new RealTimeCustomPlot();
    setWidget(m_rtplot);
    setVisible(true);
}

void QmlPlot::rescaleFromQml()
{
  resize(parentObject()->sceneBoundingRect().size());   
}
```

There must be some better way to achieve this, so my question is :

How can I make my QGraphicsProxyWidget to react the the scaling of the root item ?
On what event should i react ? in which event handler ?

UPDATE 1:

I edited the non-sense I was doing in rescaleFromQml() to something a little better.

To rephrase my whole question : instead of connecting manually some signal to my rescaleFromQml() method, in which Event handler should I put it ? and to react to which Event ?